# Write multiple objects to external json file

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I want a quickly dump objects into an external json file every time a form is submitted. However, using fs.writeFile only overwrites the one object rather than adding a new object.

How do I add a new object to the external file?

Object (JSON.stringify)

```
{"salary":"6000","poops":"6","time":"5","toCost":"$1.44"}
```

JS

```
  fs.writeFile('data.json', JSON.stringify(data), function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('It\'s saved!');
```

Comment: `fs.writeFile only overwrites the one object rather than adding a new object` => you don't have the choice. If you want, you can handle yourself several .json in order to group objects, and only update the groups you need to.

Answer (score 1):

```
fs.appendFile('data.json', JSON.stringify(data), function(err){
}
```

If i understood correctly, everytime you write an object to your file, the previous object is erased from file. That happens because *writeFile(file, data[, options], callback)* replaces the file if already exists. You can check [here](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback) for better explanation.